# Create a global shortcut for "New Message" for Mail in OS X Lion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, apple-mail

How could I create a key shortcut in OS X Lion so when I am using Safari, I type these keys and inmediately a "New Message" window from Mail.app shows up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options how to do this without third party software.

---

The easiest way is to create a *Service* in Automator:

Open Automator, create a new *Service* that receives *no input* in *any application* and add a single *New Mail Message* action. Customize some field (e.g. recipient) you want to set default values for.

Save as any name, and it's available in every application's *Services* menu. Assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.

[image]

---

Another options is AppleScript:

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true}
end tell
```

This uses Mail's API that behaves slightly differently than the UI in Lion with full-screen mode. You have most flexibility using AppleScript if you have additional requirements, but it's more difficult.

Open Automator like described above, and create a Service with a single *Run AppleScript* action. Paste the code into its text box.

---

The Services menu already has several services related to email by default, you just need to assign keyboard shortcuts:

- *New Email To Address* (when an email address in text is selected)
- *New Email With Attachment* (when a file is selected)
- *New Email With Selection* (when some text is selected)

---

If you use an application launcher such as [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/), [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), or [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), they might have this functionality already. For example, in LaunchBar, it's called *New Mail Message*.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred (with the Powerpack) provides an easy way to assign shortcuts to scripts as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versio of Alfred, you can follow this:
Features -> Contacts, then click 'Email' tab. 
By default, after invoking Alfred, if you type 'email' (followed the email address of the contact), then you can get the new message window.
This is not exactly a keyboard shortbut, but very close.